# Using array values as array names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass an array value into a function as an arg and then use it's value to reference another array. I know that sounds a bit complicated but I am doing it for a reason ;) I THINK that showProject thinks that project1 is a string as it returns only 'p' and ... Any help appreciated?

```
var projects = ["project1","project2"];

var project1 = ["image1","image2"];
var project2 = ["image1","image2"];

function showProject(arr){

    console.log(arr[0]);

}

//why isn't this showing image 1 in project 1 array?
showProject(projects[0]);
```

Fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/4ryLT/

Comment: smells like you need to use JSON :)

Comment: Yes, you are passing the string `"project1"` to the function which correclty alerts `"p"`. So what is the question?

Comment: *why isn't this showing image 1 in project 1 array?* because `project1` neither `project2` are being used inside `showProject()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ryLT/2/)

```
var project1 = ["image1","image2"];
var project2 = ["image1","image2"];

var projects = [project1,project2];

function showProject(arr){

    alert(arr[0]);

}

showProject(projects[0]);
```

Set arrays as elements of `projects` array.

Comment: My cookies, you took em! ='(

Answer (score 0):

```
var projects = ["project1","project2"];

var project1 = ["image1","image2"];
var project2 = ["image1","image2"];

function showProject(arr){

    console.log(eval(arr)[0]);

}

showProject(projects[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

is `var projects` referring to the other two variables?
If so, remove the `""` and put them in a different order

```
var project1 = ["image1","image2"];
var project2 = ["image1","image2"];
var projects = [project1,project2];

function showProject(arr){

alert(arr[0]);

}

showProject(projects[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ryLT/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this

```
var projects = [];

projects["project1"] = ["image1","image2"];
projects["project2"] = ["image1","image2"];


function showProject(arr){

   alert(arr[0]);

}

showProject(projects["project1"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

without change your logic:

```
var projects = ["project1","project2"];
var project1 = ["image1","image2"];
var project2 = ["image1","image2"];


function showProject(arr){

    console.log(eval(arr)[0]);

}
showProject(projects[0]);
```

byee

Comment: How is this different than @AlexanderNenkov's answer?

Comment: i see the @AlexanderNenkov after post. Because before my post the AlexanderNenkov answer was "unformatted". if you see i edit the answer and than i see that we write same code... your comment is useless.